# Register Caddy HTTP server as a service in Ubuntu 14

Tags: 14.04, upstart, services

I have a question regarding how to install an application as a service in Ubuntu 14. I am trying to register the HTTP server Caddy. I was following the instructions provided [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-host-a-website-with-caddy-on-ubuntu-16-04) however that intructions are for Ubuntu 16 and I get stucked in the part of register the application as a service due that Ubuntu 14 doesn't have systemctl command, the scipts that they ask to register as a service is [This one](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mholt/caddy/master/dist/init/linux-systemd/caddy.service)
This should be a really basic thing but I am not skillable in Ubuntu, so I would like if someone help me to register that as a service.
Thank you so much!

Comment: Upstart is almost completely unlike systemd. There is no simple way to adapt systemd to Upstart. You must *learn* Upstart: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/ . Of course, the day you upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu your Upstart knowledge will become obsolete.

Comment: It's much better if you tell us exactly what you did, rather which instructions you followed. We cannot know how accurately you "followed" the instructions. We cannot see the error messages produced by your system. Why would you expect 16.04 directions to work on Ubuntu 14?

Comment: I would upgrade to 16.04